# how to export a text file with PadRight space android

Tags: android, text, export

I want to ask export data to text file with spaces(PadRight) like this

Date (max 10 characters) and Barcode (max 14 characters) and Qty 1 (max 8 characters) and Qty 2 (max 8 characters)

```
Date       Barcode        Q1       Q2
--------------------------------------
21/03/2022,123456        ,10      ,4
21/03/2022,0909          ,3       ,9
```

now i don't use spaces(pad) like this

Date Barcode Q1 Q2

21/03/2022,123456,10,4

21/03/2022,0909,3,9

This is my code

```
  btn_export.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        SQLiteDatabase db = controller.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor c = null;
    
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) { //main code begins here
            try {
                c = db.rawQuery("select TanggalScan,KodeBarcode,QtyGudang,QtyToko from tblscandata", null);
                int rowcount = 0;
                int colcount = 0;
    
                File sdCardDir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
                String filename = "OPANAME.txt";

                File saveFile = new File(sdCardDir,filename);
                FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(saveFile);
                Log.e("File path", filename);
    
                BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
                rowcount = c.getCount();
                colcount = c.getColumnCount();
                if (rowcount > 0) {
                    c.moveToFirst();
    
                  
                    for (int i = 0; i < rowcount; i++) {
                        c.moveToPosition(i);
                        for (int j = 0; j < colcount; j++) {
                            if (j != colcount - 1)
                                bw.write(c.getString(j) + ",");
                            else
                                bw.write(c.getString(j));
                        }
                        bw.newLine();
                    }
                    bw.flush();
                    lbl.setText("Exported Successfully.");
    
                    controller = new DBController(getApplicationContext());
                    SQLiteDatabase db = controller.getWritableDatabase();
    
                    db.execSQL("delete from " + DBController.TableScan);
    
                }
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                if (db.isOpen()) {
                    db.close();
                    lbl.setText(ex.getMessage().toString());
                }
    
            } finally {
    
            }
        }
    });
```

this my code

Comment: And what is the problem doing so?

Comment: this my code and export txt file dont have spaces.
but i want export data txt file have spaces.

Comment: Yes, we knew that already. So i asked: And what is the problem doing so? Please answer.

Comment: String item = c.getString(j);  item = addSpaces(item, getMaxWidth(j));  bw.write(item + ",");

Comment: Implement those two functions.

Comment: can help me for your full code

Comment: And what is the problem doing that yourself?

Comment: addSpace and getMaxWidth  cannot resolved method

Comment: Implement those two functions. – Write them.

Comment: i implement like this, but addSpace and getMaxWidth error
for (int j = 0; j < colcount; j++) {
                            String item = c.getString(j);
                            item = addSpace(item, getMaxWidth(j));
                            
                            if (j != colcount - 1)
                            
                                bw.write(item + ",");
                            else
                             
                                bw.write(item);
                        }

Comment: Put code in your post. Not unreadable in comments.